# How to mount ubuntu share on other ubuntu machine?

Tags: xubuntu

I dont know much about ubuntu ,I want to  mount a ubuntu share on one machine to other ubuntu.

```
 mount -t smbfs //windowsmachine/sharefolder /mnt/share -o username=user,password=pass
```

(smbfs or cifs)
This works for only to mount a windows share on ubuntu. But how to mount a ubuntu share on ubuntu.Please help me to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the command you typed should work (except that you put two U in uusername) if you configured your Ubuntu share through Samba. It would not work if you used some other type of file sharing method, like NFS, but I believe the default method privileged by Ubuntu on the desktop is Samba.

Maybe your Ubuntu machine is not announcing its hostname on your network, and that is why you would not be able to access your shares list when typing `//ubuntu_machine`. You may want to try using your Ubuntu machine's IP address. Instead of using a machine name, you would type for example:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.100/shareforlder /mnt/share -o username=USER,password=PASSWORD
```

where 192.168.0.100 would be your IP address -- you have to substitute it by your actual IP address.

Try this, and give us some feedback!

Comment: @Alexander thank you so much.It works for me I should give IP in the place  of machine name,thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help! Now, I don't know about your network setup, but if it's not already the case, you can always configure a static IP address for your Ubuntu machine (either by configuring it statically in Ubuntu or by configuring a DHCP reservation in your DHCP server), so the machine will always have the same IP address. And if you don't have a lot of machines in your network, you can add an entry in `/etc/hosts` to resolve your machine name to that IP address. That is not mandatory, though, as using the IP address will always work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use NFS to share between Ubuntu (Linux) machines.

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Maybe be you have to install the package `rpcbind` additionally.

Comment: thank you.But I also want to mount a windows share on linux. Is there any common command to do both?